# How to get subscriptionId from Stripe Charge Object?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.net

```
StripeCharge charge=Stripe.Mapper<StripeCharge>.MapFromJson(evtData.Object.ToString());
```

I want to get subscriptionId from this Stripe charge object?How to get that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The charge has an `invoice` property that contains the identifier of the invoice corresponding to the charge if any. If it's set, you can then retrieve the invoice via [the API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_invoice). That invoice would have the `subscription` property that would be the identifier of the subscription associated with that invoice and that charge.